# Owl Carousel won't slide next item when `items` is a fraction AND loop is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, owl-carousel

If I set the `items` property to a fractal number (eg: 1.3), the carousel is unable to slide using mouse drag. It "jumps" back to the first item.

Using dots or navigation works just fine.

```js
$('.my-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1.3,
  margin: 10
  // If `loop` is set to `true`, this problem does not happen;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">


<div class="my-carousel owl-carousel">
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/000000/cacaca/?text=1">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/cacaca/000000/?text=2">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/000000/cacaca/?text=3">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/cacaca/000000/?text=4">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/000000/cacaca/?text=5">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/cacaca/000000/?text=6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reason for this is think of when you have the last slide. What will happen when you are on the last slide. Owl carousel won't show half item there which is preventing it from working.
The above method for owl carousel which uses fraction in items is not recommended. If you want to show 1 and half item use

```
stagePadding: value
```

in owl carousel's options. And if you want padding on only one side use the below CSS

**Working example**

```js
$('.my-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  margin: 10,
 stagePadding: 100
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">


<div class="my-carousel owl-carousel">
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/000000/cacaca/?text=1">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/cacaca/000000/?text=2">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/000000/cacaca/?text=3">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/cacaca/000000/?text=4">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/000000/cacaca/?text=5">
  </div>
  <div class="my-carousel__item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/256x256/cacaca/000000/?text=6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I needed. TY.